# Adding a tableView inside a tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to use a table view inside a table view cell. This is my code

```
class TableViewInsideCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = (self as! UITableViewDataSource)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
          return 5
      }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell( withIdentifier: "identifier",for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

}
```

I am getting errors telling me that `numberOfSections, numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt` doese not override any method from its supercclass.

Comment: because you inherited from UITableViewCell, and not from UITableViewController (where the functions are declared), just delete the override.

Comment: Did yout got any error if you use like this         tableView.dataSource = self

Comment: Have you written the override keyword by yourself ? Remove these methods and let the xcode auto conform to your protocol AKA UITableViewDataSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you conform to a protocol, you should just **Implement** the method body.

When you subclass a class, you may `Override` the method.

When you are using a custom `TableViewController` you `override` methods because you are not the one who conforms to the `UITableViewDataSource`, the superview (UITableViewController) is.

But if you are not inheriting from `UITableViewController`, like your case that is inheriting from the `UITableViewCell`, that method is not in the superclass and you should implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using `UITableView` inside `UITableViewCell`. I suggest you to use `UITableView` with `UITableViewCell` which has custom `UIView` and inside this `UIView` you have `UICollectionView` with custom `UICollectionCell`.